# How can keep the interface unchanged when input focus moving with mouse?

Tags: user-interface, input, focus

Info on my os and window manager and desktop environment.

```
debian@debian:~$  uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.92-2 (2022-02-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
debian@debian:~$  dpkg -l openbox
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version         Architecture Description
+++-==============-===============-============-=====================================================================
ii  openbox        3.6.1-9+deb11u1 amd64        standards-compliant, fast, light-weight and extensible window manager
debian@debian:~$  dpkg -l lxde
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  lxde           11           all          metapackage for LXDE
```

I opened two applications ,notepad and gvim, both of them contains one window,the input focus is on the gvim's window.

[image]

If i move the input focus into notepad's window with mouse ,the gvim's interface dispear.
How can move the input focus into notepad's window with mouse ,at the same time ,the gvim's interface remains on the top of notepad?

More generally,i opened terminal , at the same time, watching movie with smplayer.

[image]

If i move input focus into terminal with mouse,the smplayer's window dispear,how can input command in the terminal and watch my movie simutaniously.

Comment: What window manager are you using? Its job is to make such decisions.

Comment: debian+openbox+lxde.